# Как запустить 2 проекта laravel на одном компьютере?

Tags: php, laravel

Есть два проекта, с которыми работаю одновременно. И приходится постоянно переключатся через артисан между ними, так как не могу найти решение, каким образом можно запустить их одновременно.

Может вы знаете решение, где что прописать, или может есть где почитать, или есть готовое решение, которое уже ранее было разжовано.

Буду благодарен любой помощи, так как очень неудобно каждый раз переключаться между проектами

Comment: что вы вкладываете в слова - запустить их одновременно ?

Comment: @zalex запускаю командой php artisan serve. Запускается на хосте http:\127.0.0.1:8000. И чтобы запустить другой проект, то нужно этот отключить и запустить другой.

Comment: Можно прописать порт, например `php artisan serve --port=8001`

Comment: @Simon То что нужно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Измени порт проекта через artisan

Первый проект запусти через

```
php artisan --port 8001
```

Второй проект

```
php artisan --port 8002
```

Советую запускать их не в IDE , а через gitbash , так как при закрытии IDE проекты будут активными